# "With his face (being) red, he shouted at the top of his lungs." Which sentence do I have to use?

Tags: grammaticality, zero-copula

Which of these are correct? And if both are correct, what's more natural?

With his face red, he shouted at the top of his lungs.

With his face being red, he shouted at the top of his lungs.

Comment: I assume that what you really mean is that ***due to*** his shouting his faced turned red.  The way your sentences are written it describes a 2-step process,  Step 1: Get your face to turn red.  Step 2: while maintaining your red face shout as loudly as you can.

Comment: "At the top of his lung" is not an idiom. "At the top of his voice" is.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say *He shouted till he went red in the face*.

Comment: We have two lungs, and they work together.

Comment: No, it's actually a relatively common idiom, but it's "lungs", not "lung". A human has a pair, unless somehow otherwise incapacitated.

Comment: Lectifyingo, it would seem there's some ambiguity to your meaning here. Please explain in further detail the state of the man before and after yelling, and what the nature of the yelling is. I suspect you mean that he was already angry and red faced, and *then* yelled as loud as he could.

Comment: In U.S. vernacular English, you could say "Red-faced, he shouted at the top of his lungs." This is much like the more British vernacular form that Colin Fine suggests in an answer below.

Comment: I think the reason "with his facing [being] red" sounds unnatural is in part because "red-faced" and "red in the face" are common idioms which are briefer. The inclusion of "being" suggests that his red face caused or at least predicted his shouting, whereas the sentence without "being" is more likely to suggest simultaneity.

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical. Neither is natural, but I'm struggling to explain why.

I think it's that we don't use *with* for a temporary condition or state, but rather a participial clause or postmodifying adjectival. So:

> Head aching, I walked home.
>
> Eyes bright, she spoke to me.
>
> Arms folded, he eyed the group.

We do use *with* for an accompanying action, though:

> With a toss of her head, she left.

So the natural version of your example, for me, would be

> His face red, he shouted at the top of his voice.

(Or *red-faced*).

Comment: With *lungs* pluralized, "top of his lungs" is quite common in AmE. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=top+of+his+lungs%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctop+of+his+lungs%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ctop+of+his+voice%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ctop+of+his+voice%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctop%20of%20his%20lungs%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20of%20his%20lungs%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20of%20his%20voice%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20of%20his%20voice%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: 'His face being red, he ...' demands, I'd say, the absolute clause as a reason for the independent clause. The reduced form doesn't.

Comment: @Peter Shor If *at the top of his lungs*, is an American idiom, perhaps the British equivalent would be *he bellowed*. For that is what lungs are, aren't they - bellows?